# How do i store Url in a variable and check if its is matchable with another url

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I was doing quick changes in my site and i am little stuck into one situation, what i want is that i want to store the URL of a specific page in a $variable and i want to check weather that stored $variable url is match able with my custom link that i like to provide .

for example my header url is https://jonty/page-1.com   and i want to store in $variable,

and also i want to apply condition to check weather my $variable url is similar to  https://jonty/page-1.com

```
if($variable == https://jonty/page-1.com) {
      //condition
   }
```

Comment: What happens with the current code? This is pseudo code, right?

Comment: You can use ```location.href``` to get the current url

Comment: @user3783243 Well this is just the testing code written by myself. It is not working , i am confused how to store url in a $variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get user's current URL via:

```
$variable = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

So you can check whether the condition is true or not

```
if($variable == 'https://example.com/test') {
    // Blob Blob Blob
}
```